# AllPalletsWithSystem trait not implemented for Executive when running tests

Tags: runtime, substrate-parachain-template, try-runtime

I'm migrating a project from `substrate-node-template` to `substrate-parachain-template` and I'm encountering an issue when running tests. I understand that this is completely dependent of my local code and probably result of a merge issue, nevertheless I would be thankful if somebody can give me some advice. The problem I am facing is the following compilation error:

```
  error[E0599]: the function or associated item `try_runtime_upgrade` exists for struct `frame_executive::Executive<Runtime, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>>, ChainContext<Runtime>, Runtime, (frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>, parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_sudo::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_treasury::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_authorship::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_collator_selection::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_session::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_aura::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_aura_ext::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_utility::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_vesting::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_scheduler::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_uniques::Pallet<Runtime>)>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
     --> /substrate-parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:972:31
      |
  972 |       let weight = Executive::try_runtime_upgrade().unwrap();

note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied: 
      `(frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>, parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_sudo::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_treasury::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_authorship::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_collator_selection::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_session::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_aura::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_aura_ext::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_utility::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_vesting::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_scheduler::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_uniques::Pallet<Runtime>): TryState<u32>`
```

I've checked the definition of Executive, it's as follows:

```rust
/// Executive: handles dispatch to the various modules.
pub type Executive =
  frame_executive::Executive<Runtime, Block, frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>, Runtime, AllPalletsWithSystem>;
```

It means that `AllPalletsWithSystem` was not created with all the pallets and the system. I know this type is generated in `construct_runtime` and the pallets are of course declared there:

```rust
// Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
construct_runtime!(
  pub enum Runtime where
    Block = Block,
    NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
    UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
  {
    // System support stuff.
    System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>} = 0,
    ParachainSystem: cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::{
      Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Inherent, Event<T>, ValidateUnsigned,
    } = 1,
    Timestamp: pallet_timestamp::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Inherent} = 2,
    ParachainInfo: parachain_info::{Pallet, Storage, Config} = 3,
    Sudo: pallet_sudo = 7,
    Treasury: pallet_treasury = 8,

    // Monetary stuff.
    Balances: pallet_balances::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>} = 10,
    TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment::{Pallet, Storage, Event<T>} = 11,


    // Collator support. The order of these 4 are important and shall not change.
    Authorship: pallet_authorship::{Pallet, Call, Storage} = 20,
    CollatorSelection: pallet_collator_selection::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>} = 21,
    Session: pallet_session::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event, Config<T>} = 22,
    Aura: pallet_aura::{Pallet, Storage, Config<T>} = 23,
    AuraExt: cumulus_pallet_aura_ext::{Pallet, Storage, Config} = 24,

    // XCM helpers.
    XcmpQueue: cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>} = 30,
    PolkadotXcm: pallet_xcm::{Pallet, Call, Event<T>, Origin, Config} = 31,
    CumulusXcm: cumulus_pallet_xcm::{Pallet, Event<T>, Origin} = 32,
    DmpQueue: cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>} = 33,

    // Customizations
    Utility: pallet_utility::{Pallet, Call, Event} = 40,
    // Vesting. Usable initially, but removed once all vesting is finished.
    Vesting: pallet_vesting::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>} = 41,
    Scheduler: pallet_scheduler = 42,
    Uniques: pallet_uniques::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>} = 43,
  }
);
```

So where is the problem coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably not passing the `try-runtime` feature down to all the pallets in your runtime.
The feature needs to be propagated to all pallets ([Example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/09f2d1a1c60d0d41ff88e008480e8495b8488a17/runtime/kusama/Cargo.toml#L261)) and ideally also dependencies, otherwise the `AllPalletsWithSystem` will not implement `TryState`.