# trait bounds not satisfied with Executive::try_runtime_upgrade()

Tags: substrate-contracts-node, try-runtime, cli

I'm attempting to integrate try-runtime into substrate-contracts-node and I get the following error when I call `Executive::try_runtime_upgrade()`:

```
Compiling contracts-node-runtime v0.24.0 (/Users/bruno/src/substrate-contracts-node/runtime)
  error[E0599]: the function or associated item `try_runtime_upgrade` exists for struct `Executive<Runtime, Block<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, ...>, ..., ..., ..., ...>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
     --> /Users/bruno/src/substrate-contracts-node/runtime/src/lib.rs:600:28
      |
  600 |             let weight = Executive::try_runtime_upgrade(checks).unwrap();
      |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds
      |
      = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/bruno/src/substrate-contracts-node/target/release/wbuild/contracts-node-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/contracts_node_runtime-51f958c1a37e4242.long-type-8782138364158150179.txt'
      = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
              `(frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_utility::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_randomness_collective_flip::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_authorship::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_sudo::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_contracts::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_assets::Pallet<Runtime>): hidden_include::traits::TryState<u32>`

  error[E0599]: the function or associated item `try_execute_block` exists for struct `Executive<Runtime, Block<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, ...>, ..., ..., ..., ...>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
     --> /Users/bruno/src/substrate-contracts-node/runtime/src/lib.rs:612:15
      |
  612 |             Executive::try_execute_block(block, state_root_check, signature_check, select).expect("execute-block failed")
      |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds
      |
      = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/bruno/src/substrate-contracts-node/target/release/wbuild/contracts-node-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/contracts_node_runtime-51f958c1a37e4242.long-type-8782138364158150179.txt'
      = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
              `(frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_utility::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_randomness_collective_flip::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_authorship::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_sudo::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_contracts::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_assets::Pallet<Runtime>): hidden_include::traits::TryState<u32>`
```

Here all the code changes that I have done:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/commit/0b2473a37ba540fac4af780e98faca521d9807f6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing features on the pallet crates.
The following patch fixed this:

```
diff --git a/runtime/Cargo.toml b/runtime/Cargo.toml
index 9a8d59f..4eebddd 100644
--- a/runtime/Cargo.toml
+++ b/runtime/Cargo.toml
@@ -94,9 +94,13 @@ try-runtime = [
    "frame-executive/try-runtime",
    "frame-system/try-runtime",
    "frame-support/try-runtime",
+   "pallet-assets/try-runtime",
    "pallet-authorship/try-runtime",
    "pallet-balances/try-runtime",
+   "pallet-contracts/try-runtime",
+   "pallet-randomness-collective-flip/try-runtime",
    "pallet-sudo/try-runtime",
    "pallet-timestamp/try-runtime",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/try-runtime",
+   "pallet-utility/try-runtime",
 ]
```

But it is a duplicate of [AllPalletsWithSystem trait not implemented for Executive when running tests](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6576/allpalletswithsystem-trait-not-implemented-for-executive-when-running-tests).